# How to vectorize this matrix building operation?

Tags: python, for-loop, vectorization

**Problem:**

Vectorize the building of a matrix where certain elements are a function determined by whether or not a particular triple index exists in a dictionary. Other elements are 0.

**Code:**

This is simple to implement using for loops:

```
# specify matrix size. In this example it is 4*4 but they get much, much bigger
mat_size = 4

# create empty numpy array
matt = np.zeros((mat_size, mat_size))

# index_list is a list of tuples which are subtracted element-wise in the for loops to form a new triple index used to access the coming dictionary
# the list of tuples gets larger as the matrix size increases
index_list = [(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 2), (0, 1, 1), (0, 2, 0), (1, 1, 0)]

# the dictionary of functions:
# keys are a tuple of integers
# values are the functions to be evaluated to form the matrix
# there are more keys in the actual problem but this is for the minimal working example
func_dict = {(0, 0, 0): lambda a : a + 10, 
             (0, 0, -2): lambda a : a - 3, 
             (0, 0, -1): lambda a : a**5, 
             (0, 0, 1): lambda a : a*10 + 5,
             (0, 1, 0): lambda a : a/3 + 2, 
             (0, 1, -2): lambda a : a*2 + a**4, 
             (0, 1, -1): lambda a : a/4 * 76, 
             (0, 1, 1): lambda a : a*19 / 3, 
            }

# only loop over half the matrix as they are always symmetric
for H in range(mat_size):
    for J in range(H, mat_size):
        x  = index_list[J][0] - index_list[H][0] # subtract first tuple elements
        y  = index_list[J][1] - index_list[H][1] # subtract second tuple elements
        z  = index_list[J][2] - index_list[H][2] # subtract third tuple elements
        
        # check if x,y,z is in the dictionary
        if (x, y, z) in func_dict:
            matt[H,J] = func_dict[x, y, z](3.43)
        else:
            matt[H,J] = 0
```

**Output:**

An upper triangular (with diagonal) matrix:

```
[[13.43       39.3         3.14333333  0.        ]
 [ 0.         13.43       65.17       39.3       ]
 [ 0.          0.         13.43        0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.         13.43      ]]
```

I parallelized the outer loop which is the current implementation I have been using and has been suitably fast enough. The matrix sizes are now becoming larger and after profiling this is the limiting step which I need to speed up as it gets called repeatedly.

I can feel this problem will allow for vectorization but after several attempts always results in a loop which then ends up being comparable with the parallelized version.

**Is there an effective way to vectorize this problem, removing any loop(s)?**

Comment: Not sure what the tuple and tuple subtraction is for. Could you clarify that? Why would you need to do a for loop to get these indices?

Comment: Quick answer: Probably not, if you're using standard Python. Numpy is likely to have vector-oriented operations, so you'd have to write your code in numpy-style. You could also reduce the two loops into one using a `zip`.

Comment: The J and H index subtraction in the for loops is a means of collapsing triple indices representing rows and columns into a single (new) index tuple. This problem stems from a quantum mechanics problem I am solving. Each matrix element is turned on or off dictated by whether the index (x,y,z) exists in the index dictionary.

I have tried a version which uses numpy from the start but I eventually run into requiring an explicit loop.